# Select drop-list item without triggering onchange event?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to populate a drop-list with several items and select a default item:

```
<select onchange="DoSomething(this)">
    <option value="abb">This is the second item</option>
    <option value="abc" selected>This is the third item</option>
    etc...
</select>
```

However I don't want the onChange event to fire (or I want the code triggered by onChange to be ignored) until the **user** selects an item. At the moment the onChange event fires as the page loads and the selected item is chosen by default.

Can I wrap this code in PHP to achieve this - if so how?

Comment: Do you specifically want php code or is javascript acceptable? Also why can't you use `onclick` and attach `onchange` from within the `onclick` handler?

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense. Your select option will load the option `This is the third item` because of the `selected` command on that tag. When you change this option, say to `this is the second item` then your onchange gets fired. If it is firing when the page load than you have another call to it somewhere else.

Comment: You could generate the onchange event from javascript after page has loaded.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - assume "DoSomething" makes an alert box appear. As it stands the alert box appears as soon as the page loads because the drop-list has a default item. I only want the alert box to appear if the user chooses a different item from the drop-list.

Comment: Plus you openned a `<select>` tag and did not close it you, instead you use `</section>`

Comment: Andy, that should not happen, unless you are setting the selected attribute via js

Comment: @AndyGroom As I said before. The onchange event only gets Fired if you change the option on the select element. If it is getting fired you have ANOTHER script calling it when the page load. If you loike a prove of that, change the name of this function say to `DoSomethingElse` and its definition also `funtion DoSomethingElse` and see it it gets load. Plus close the right tag, it is not `</section>` it is `</select>`

Answer (score 0):

?!

Manipulating the HTML DOM directly in JavaScript doesn't fire events.  You can even call `myForm.submit()` and the browser will not fire the form's onsubmit event, therefore bypassing client-side onsubmit validation.

I don't know what you've tried, but this is one way to select for example the first item of the drop-down list:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = true;
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/Jawh6/)

Crude, I know.  Usually your forms and fields would be named or otherwise identified so you can address them more excplicitly: e.g. `document.myForm.mySelect.options[0].selected = true;`

---

Since your PHP is already setting the 'selected' attribute on the option (or your question isn't very well tagged), this would be the best place to set the default option when the page loads, that requires no JavaScript at all.

If you're interested in how to get PHP to write out the HTML for a select element and correctly assign the selected attribute to the intended option, I reckon you need to write a new question to attract the PHP folk.

---

Either you have other calls to your DoSomething function, or you've oversimplified your example and you're actually using a framework to bind the event handler to the field and maybe you accidentally called your function instead of assigning it, e.g.:

```
mySelect.onchange = DoSomething(); // oops, this calls DoSomething right away.

mySelect.onchange = DoSomething; // this sets DoSomething as the event handler.
```